# Intraclass Correlations ICC1, ICC2, ICC3?

Tags: spss, intraclass-correlation

I am doing some research for my teacher training.  I am looking at the agreement between student-assessment and teacher-assessment.  Essentially there are 4 tasks.  Students scored the task and I scored the task.

- Task 1 by studentA: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentA,
- Task 2 by studentA: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentA,
- Task 3 by studentA: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentA,
- Task 4 by StudentA: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentA,
- Task 1 by StudentB: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentB,
- Task 2 by StudentB: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentB,
- Task 3 by StudentB: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentB,
- Task 4 by StudentB: Judge1 - Teacher, Judge2 - StudentB,

I have read Strout and Fleiss but I am unsure what case the above is.  Can anyone help?

Comment: On what scale were the tasks rated? And what do you mean by 'task'?

Comment: Rated from 0 to 100.  The task was to write a simple piece of code

Comment: 4 different pieces of code, one for each task